# Do there exists art works representing high math-related topics?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, art

I'm not looking for pieces in which math related object appears with allegoric meanings, but works which aim to to have mathematical objects as principal subjects.

Specifically, I was wondering if anyone knows nice rapresentations (in the non-mathematics sense) of finite small group, with an aesthetic intent beside a faithfulness one.

Comment: Fractals are usually the first example people mention, although that's not about small finite groups. Cayley graphs are somewhat aesthetic, if you're into that sort of things.

Comment: See Durer's *Melencolia I*.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone has gone any further in Cayley graphs' direction, beyond an useful sketch to visualize the group's structure, toward an actual artistic purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The drawings of [M.C.Escher](http://www.crystalinks.com/escher.html) immediately come to mind.

See [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/201006/rtx100600706p.pdf) nice paper on the subject.

***EDIT***

Also check these very interesting and illuminating articles posted below (comment section) by user **Quasicoherent**-

"[Artful Mathematics: The Heritage of M. C. Escher Celebrating Mathematics Awareness Month](http://www.ams.org/notices/200304/fea-escher.pdf)"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's [another paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200304/fea-escher.pdf) and [accompanying website](http://escherdroste.math.leidenuniv.nl/) on one of Escher's works.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Very nice and more rigorous than the one I posted. I will edit the answer to refer to your comment. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in higher group theory, check out [Anatoly Fomenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Fomenko):

[Simplicial spaces, cellular spaces, crystal and liquid](http://chronologia.org/en/math_impressions/poster086.html)
[image]

[Homotopy groups of spheres](http://chronologia.org/en/math_impressions/poster034.html);
[Discrete groups generated by reflections](http://chronologia.org/en/math_impressions/poster094.html)
[image] 
[image]

[Spectral sequences and orbits of the action of groups](http://chronologia.org/en/math_impressions/poster030.html);
[A 2-adic solenoid](http://chronologia.org/en/math_impressions/poster018.html)
[image]
[image]